# Increase and Decrease Motor Speed

Tags: motor, speed

I'm a newbie on Arduino and I'm doing an exercise about the Motor controller 
"Increase the motor speed from zero to maxium (255) and then decrease slowly from the maximum to the minium."
Here's my code. I don't know whether it's true or not. So, can anyone help me to check it and give me some advice how to do better on Arduino ?

```
int i;
void setup()
{
   pinMode(motor, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
   for (i=0; i<=255; i++)
   {
   analogWrite(motor, i);
   }

   for (i=255; i>=0; i--)
   {
   analogWrite(motor, i);
   }
}
```

I also have one other problem :D that I don't know what will happen if I set the analogWrite value to 300.

Thank you so much.

Comment: @per1234 Per, why unclear?

Comment: It's unclear because there is no question in it, just a "check my code please"...

Comment: "check my code please" is a valid question according to https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work, as you don't give it any time to do anything. The PWM works about 1kHz and motor needs much more time to start rotating. And you are sending values as fast as possible (it means microseconds for every analogWrite)

And `analogWrite(300)` without changing the Arduino default settings means it overflows to value `300 % 256 = 44`. All Timers are set near to 1kHz and 8bit resolution by Arduino core.